# concatinating two array elements with a string within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I am trying to combine two array elements with the string "OR" and create one string of elements.

The array looks like this:
`$myarray = array(2282396,1801345)`

This is the code i have used.

```
$bool = ' OR ';
foreach($myarray as $element){

echo $element .= $bool;
}
```

I trying to get this output after looping using a foreach loop.
`2282396 OR 1801345`

However, the output i get looks like this:
`2282396 OR 1801345 OR`

How do i get rid of the 'OR' after the second element? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if you're in the first/last iteration or not.

```
$first = true;
$bool = ' OR ';
foreach ($myarray as $element) {
    if (!$first) {
        echo $bool;
    }
    echo $element; 
    $first = false;
}
```

If your array is indexed by numeric indexes 0-x, you an use

```
$bool = ' OR ';
foreach ($myarray as $key => $element) {
    if ($key > 0) {
        echo $bool;
    }
    echo $element; 
}
```

Comment: @dWinder: sure, I know. The OP asks for `foreach` loop. It can be simplified code in question, probably doesn't need to use just `echo`, etc. The OP asks for the `foreach` loop, so there is an answer with `foreach` loop.

Comment: Works like a charm @panther. I am accepting this as an answer

Comment: I don't think the OP knew what he wants - this is our job to not just answer him but also to teach him - as sometime he doesn't know what he need

Answer (score 2):

Use `implode` as:

```
echo implode(" OR ", $myarray);
```

Documentation [implode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/fnc2h)